# How to get a reference to system manager from anywhere?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flex4, stage

How do you get a reference to the system manager from any class in your application?

For example say I have:

```
/** 
 * Value object class
 **/
public class Person {

    public function Person():void {
        var sm:SystemManager = ...; // need reference to sm
        var stage:Stage = sm.stage;
    }

    public var name:String;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/FlexGlobals.html#topLevelApplication) for this. It will return a reference to your main Application instance. And from there you can easily get the SystemManager instance, like so:

```
var sm:SystemManager = Application(FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication).systemManager
```